# XAMPP php redirect to html on C drive

Tags: php, html, web, xampp, web-development-server

I'm new to web dev, and I'm running into an issue building a site.  Unfortunately, I haven't found an answer to this exact problem yet...

I'm using XAMPP to test.  I have a HTML page (in a package on my C drive because it is not live yet) - and I'm trying to check if the input of a text box is in a database or not.  Once the submit button is clicked, it directs to a php page on the server that successfully executes the query - but here's the problem...  I want to direct back to page A if the query is found, and page B if not. Both page A and B have buttons that call other html pages in the package, so I'm trying to redirect back to html pages on my C drive:

```
    if($nameFound == True) {
    // echo "User Name: " . $userinput . " is in the database!";
    $URL="C://<path to html file>/A.html"; 

    header ("Location: $URL"); 
    exit();
} else {
    // echo "User Name: " . $userinput . " is not in the database!";
    $URL="C://<path to html file>/B.html"; 

    header ("Location: $URL"); 
    exit();
}
```

This, does not work, however - it tries to find a non-existent php page on the server.

Does anyone know how to achieve this goal?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect back to the page URL instead of file path.

```
header('Location: /A.html');
```

or

```
header('Location: http://localhost/A.html');
```

Both pages should be being served by your local XAMPP install.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to give the absolute or complete path of the file as you mentioned here:

```
$URL="C://<path to html file>/A.html";
```

you should use relative paths when redirecting in php for example if you have a folder as "demo" in your C://xampp/htdocs/demo and your A.html is in testApp folder:

```
header('Location: testApp/A.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both  [Lois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9490918/louis) and [Hussnain Raza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4548935/hussnain-raza) - the solution (for me) was a combination of their solutions.  First, n00b mistake, I did not upload the html pages to XAMPP. Next, since my php is in a php folder and my html is in a pages folder, I had to navigate out of the current folder and into a new one... SO, the solution was:

1. Upload html (and related files) to XAMPP server.
2. Change paths in php file to `//localhost/<parent folder>/pages/A.html`
3. Fix paths in all other relevant files.

Thanks for putting me on the right track @Lois & @Hussnain.  I'd upvote both answers if I could.